# Traversing multiple rows : multiple column to 1 row multiple column

Tags: subquery

I'm a beginner. I have 4 tables like below .  I'm able to acheive result with either one of UAT, IT, Prod but not all 3...

Should we use pivot?
 Please help to achieve result.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show a concrete example of your code.

Comment: select r.request_number,r.description, r.creation_date, u.parameter29 as proposed_deployment_date, wft.approval_date as uat_date, v.parameter14 as actual_deploy_date, r.closed date 
from table2 u,table2 v , table1 r , table3 wft  
where u.batch_number=1 and  v.batch_number=3 and wft.step_id=41075 and r.request_number=u.request_number and 
r.request_number=v.request_number and wft.request_number = r.request_number order by r.request number;

Comment: Please place it in the question body, not as a comment.    http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask